# Use reflection to access property based on parameter received - Java

Tags: java, spring, oop, reflection

I'm developing a project in Spring, and I have a configuration file which maps areas to sites, something like:

```
===========
Areas Mapper
===========

Sites:
    USA:
        - Arizona
        - Florida
        - New York
        - Texas
    Europe:
        - Germany
        - Russia
        - Poland
```

Now, I get the area as a parameter from an API call, and I need to return a list of sites based on this param.

I was wondering, if using reflection in this case in order to access the list of sites dynamically is the right way to do it? and if so, how would you do it?

This is what I've done so far:

**Configuration Class:**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "Sites")
@Component
@Data
public class AreasToSitesMapperConfig {

    protected List<String> usa;
    protected List<String> europe;
    protected List<String> australia;
}
```

**Mapper Class:**

```
@Component
public class AreasToSitesMapper {

    @Inject
    private AreasToSitesMapperConfig areasToSitesMapperConfig;

    public List<String> getSitesForArea(String area) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        Field field = AreasToSitesMapperConfig.class.getDeclaredField(area);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(this);

        //Of course I can implement it as follows, but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it :  
        if (area == "USA") return areasToSitesMapperConfig.usa ......
    }
}
```

This is the call from the service:

```
List<AreaDataDAO> areaDataList = areasRepository.getDataBySiteInAndDateBetweenOrderByDateDesc(
            areasToSitesMapper.getSitesForArea(area),     
        );
```

As you can see, 'area' is passed to 'getSitesForArea' function, and based on this parameter I need to return the relevant list.

Comment: Why not use an enum? Using reflection to inspect internal string values is dead wrong. Your list of sites is something that should provide a reasonable way to look it up.

Comment: Reflection is clearly not (as almost always) the right tool for the job. Just write the few `if` blocks necessary to get the right list, or use a Map<String, List<String>>, or whatever simple solution that doesn't need any reflection.

Comment: It felt wrong to use reflection and this is why I asked for second opinion.